# How to download text file in private folder and show text file contents in text view

Tags: android, textview, text-files, android-download-manager

I Want to download text file from server in private folder, that should not be accessible to user. In short I want to store that file in Application Folder only, not on memory card/internal memory. Once download complete I would like to show the text file in text view. If the file is already downloaded or present in folder, then just want to show that file contents. Can someone help me please? Thanks in Advance.

Here is the code -

```
            url = new URL("https://tmpfiles.org/dl/11433/baby_shark_dodo.txt");
            connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.connect();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

            try {
                File mydir = getApplicationContext().getDir("Songs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                if(!mydir.exists()){
                    mydir.mkdir();
                }
                final File file = new File(mydir,"Test.txt");
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bufferLength = 0;

                while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
                    fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                }
                fileOutputStream.close();
                connection.disconnect();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Have you done anything?

Comment: Yes, I have code for downloading file but without progress bar... adding code in Question